# How to retrieve return value and resultset from Stored Proc using Linq To SQL?

Tags: linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

Consider a stored procedure like this:

```
create procedure p1 as
begin
    declare @n1 int;
    select  @n1=count(*)
    from  Employee;

    select top 100 *
    from   Employee;
    return @n1;
end
```

How can I capture `@n1` as well as the Employee resultset using Linq To SQL in C#?

Answer (score 1):

You need an OUTPUT parameter

```
create procedure p1(@n1 int =0 OUTPUT ) as
begin
    select 
       @n1=count(*)
    from
       Employee

    select top 100
        *
    from
        Employee
end
```

--And remember, you have to indicate a parameter is for output when you execute the proc

```
Declare @val int
exec p1 @val OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

```
//I can access the resultset as following:
var emps = dataContext1.p1;

//I can get to @n1 by this:
int i1=int(emps).ReturnValue;
```